# Perl opens socket connection for every kafka message sent

Tags: perl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Perl kafka Producer, Kafka::Producer opens socket for every message published to kafka .

Is there any way that can be avoided .
Here is my code ,

```
$connection = Kafka::Connection->new( host => "kafka-1", port => 9092 );
$producer = Kafka::Producer->new( Connection => $connection );

sub _send_beacon {
    my @beacons = @_;

    my @array = (0..$num_of_partitions-1);

    my $randomelement = $array[rand @array];

        $producer->send(

            'raghavendra',          # topic

            $randomelement ,

            [
                @beacons
            ]
        );
undef $producer;

$connection->close;

undef $connection;
```

Comment: i would suggest you not to use this module - if i have to be ridiculously polite i would say this module is far from perfect it is very sad that this is the only PERL Kafka module which actually works and it is light years below the functionalities kafka-python offers it is sad indeed